# Error when making a Path sprite in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs4, firebug

Here's the code I'm working with. This simple function was made just to test that I was doing it correctly. Evidently, I'm not. For a reason that escapes me, unless I comment out this first function I always get the same error.

```
// Build an arrow from first to second
var buildEdge = function(first, second)
{
    var arrow;
    arrow = {
        type: 'path',
        path: "M " + first.x + " " + first.y + " " +
              "L " + second.x + " " + second.y,
        stroke: 'black'
    };
    return arrow;
};

var first = {
    type: 'circle',
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    radius: 50,

    fill: '#99FF99',
    stroke: '#55CC55',
    'stroke-width': 2
};
// .........
```

`first` and `second` are both ExtJS sprites.
When running this FireBug always provides this helpful error:

`TypeError: this[("getPath" + a.type)] is not a function
http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.2.0-gpl/ext-all.js
Line 21`

I've gone through *ext-all.js*, but I don't know much about the inner workings of ExtJS and don't want to (for this project anyway). I'll admit I'm a newbie to JavaScript, but I know this code will "compile," anyway. And yes, I do have the other sprites (`first` and `second`) displaying correctly when I remove this function.

I expect I've made some silly rookie mistake here, so any help would be welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try this code and see what happens?

```
// Build an arrow from first to second
// surface param is surface instance sprite is to be added to.
var buildEdge = function(first, second, surface)
{
    var arrow;
    arrow = Ext.create('Ext.draw.Sprite', {
        type: 'path',
        path: "M " + first.x + " " + first.y + " " +
              "L " + second.x + " " + second.y,
        stroke: 'black'
    });

    surface.add(arrow);
    arrow.show(true);

  //return arrow if you want to work with it elsewhere outside of method.
};
```

**Notes:**

Check out clasificado's comment for the surface.add() method.

*"if you programatically add a new sprite after the render event raised, you need to manually call the .show(true) method for the new sprite"*

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.draw.Surface-method-add